# Modal won't close - Twitter Bootstrap 1.40

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using Bootstrap 1.40 and whilst my modal opens without any problem, I can't seem to close it using the button I have included in the modal it self.

This is the code I am using to close it:

```
<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal-from-dom" ><img src="images/cancel_btn.png" alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" /></a>
```

and this is the code for the modal:

```
<div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div align="center"><img src="images/icon_wait.gif" alt="" border="0" /></div>
            <h5 class="logout_h5" >Blah blah</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" >
             <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal-from-dom" ><img src="images/cancel_btn.png" alt="" border="0" align="absmiddle" /></a> 
          </div>
 </div>
        <button data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn danger">Launch Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modal closing element should have the `close` class. (`class="close"`).

Also, [consider upgrading](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/upgrading.html) to the [newer bootstrap version](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) to enjoy many bugfixes and new features.